# Server disables page after several GET requests from SIM908

Tags: http, get, web-hosting, arduino-uno, sim900

I set up a free domain on 000webhost.com
I am using this as a web server to receive data from SIM908+arduino setup and store it in the database. Then display it on a web page.
I am sending the data from the SIM908 using HTTP GET requests. Basically I am sending two pieces of information, one is the location (lat and long) and other is a string. Both are sent using GET requests. The problem is very unusual so bear with me. EVERYTHING WORKS FINE, for a while. After several GET requests are sent, for some reason, 000webhost just deactivates my domain. I simply cannot access it. Every time I try to browse to the page it times out. It remains like this for around 7-8 hours after which the domain works fine again. I tried another hosting byethost.com, but GET requests from the SIM908 do not work there at all. Everything is 100% OK. The code, arduino setup everything is fine. My question is why is 000webhost stopping my domain? Really need a good answer or at least some direction, i am completely lost.

**NOTE: Please don't suggest POST method unless you explicitly know how to perform a POST operation using SIM908 AT commands, as far as I know it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the free webhost which has limitations. They will block you if your site is getting too much requests. Just read the limitations of free accounts with the server.

Look for a better free service or buy one. There is no issue with sim900 or arduino.

The following hosting service providers might be better than the one you are currently using in terms of limitations

- [Host Buddy](http://www.hostbuddy.com/) You would get two months free
- [Free Hostia](http://www.freehostia.com/)
- [Free Hosting .eu](http://freehostingeu.com)

Comment: ok! really needed a confident suggestion! give me a minute to try host buddy.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. working fine now! big thumbs up!